# Book on civilizations in different geological periods of the Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to remember the name of a scifi book, the only thing I remember is that in the history of the book, there was a civilization in every geological period on earth.
Unfortunately this is the only thing I remember, I read about it a long time ago, I already researched it and I couldn't find it.

Comment: Past or future geological periods?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dying_Earth_genre

Comment: What is the lower bound on how long ago you read it?  Was it a full book or a novella?  How was the viewpoint of the story encompassing civilisations separated by geological ages - was there time travel?

Comment: Helliconia perhaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the periods are in the future (and eventually, involve other planets), this could be *[Last and First Men](https://www.fadedpage.com/books/20200531/html.php)* by Olaf Stapledon.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_and_First_Men):

> *Last and First Men:  A Story of the Near and Far Future* is a "future history" science fiction novel written in 1930 by the British author Olaf Stapledon.  A work of unprecedented scale in the genre, it describes the history of humanity from the present onwards across two billion years and eighteen distinct human species, of which our own is the first.  The book employs a narrative conceit that, under subtle inspiration, the novelist has unknowingly been dictated a channelled text from the last human species.

Comment: Agreed; I think this is the most obvious answer.

Comment: That sounds a lot like All Tommorrows, but isnt

Comment: It was about this Olaf Stapledon novel that I had read, thank you very much.